# expected class name in c++ addon for nodejs

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

i am working on a c++ addon for nodejs. It's a probabilistic filter. What i need to do is to bind the existing c++ library to nodejs.
I am following the instructions of the documents in https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/addons.html#addons_wrapping_c_objects

And i have another example in github which shows me how a probabilistic filter in c++ is bound to nodejs: https://github.com/bbondy/bloom-filter-cpp.

I try to transform my own c++ library to a nodejs addon. And I have finished the coding now i try to build it alone with the binding.gyp. But there is always one error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muSsh.png)

However i did include the SimdBlockFilter in the class:
Here is the code for simd_block_wrap.h:

```
#ifndef simd_block_wrap_hpp
#define simd_block_wrap_hpp


#include <node.h>
#include <node_object_wrap.h>
#include "SimdBlockFilter.h"


namespace simd_block_wrap {
class simd_block_wrap : public SimdBlockFilter, public node::ObjectWrap {
public:
    static void Init(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports);
    simd_block_wrap(const int log_heap_space);

private:

    virtual ~simd_block_wrap();

    static void Add(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args);
    static void Find(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args);

    static v8::Persistent<v8::Function> constructor;
};
}
#endif /* simd_block_wrap_hpp */
```

and here is the code for binding.gyp:

```
{
"targets": [{
"target_name": "addon",
"sources": [
  "addon.cpp",
  "SimdBlockFilter.h",
  "simd_block_wrap.cpp",
  "simd_block_wrap.h",
  "hashutil.cc",
  "hashutil.h",
],

"xcode_settings": {
  "OTHER_CFLAGS": [ "-ObjC" ],
  "OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS" : ["-std=c++11","-stdlib=libc++", "-v"],
  "MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET": "10.9",
  "GCC_ENABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS": "YES",
},
}]
}
```

and also the code of SimdBlockFilter.h which is the c++ library

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>


#include <algorithm>
#include <new>

#include <immintrin.h>

#include "hashutil.h"

using uint32_t = ::std::uint32_t;
using uint64_t = ::std::uint64_t;

template<typename HashFamily =                
::cuckoofilter::TwoIndependentMultiplyShift>
class SimdBlockFilter {
private:
  // The filter is divided up into Buckets:
  using Bucket = uint32_t[8];

  // log2(number of bytes in a bucket):
  static constexpr int LOG_BUCKET_BYTE_SIZE = 5;

  static_assert(
     (1 << LOG_BUCKET_BYTE_SIZE) == sizeof(Bucket) && sizeof(Bucket)     == sizeof(__m256i),
  "Bucket sizing has gone awry.");

  // log_num_buckets_ is the log (base 2) of the number of buckets in the directory:
  const int log_num_buckets_;

  // directory_mask_ is (1 << log_num_buckets_) - 1. It is precomputed in the contructor
  // for efficiency reasons:
  const uint32_t directory_mask_;

  Bucket* directory_;

  HashFamily hasher_;

 public:
  // Consumes at most (1 << log_heap_space) bytes on the heap:
  explicit SimdBlockFilter(const int log_heap_space);
  SimdBlockFilter(SimdBlockFilter&& that)
    : log_num_buckets_(that.log_num_buckets_),
  directory_mask_(that.directory_mask_),
  directory_(that.directory_),
  hasher_(that.hasher_) {}
  ~SimdBlockFilter() noexcept;
  void Add(const uint64_t key) noexcept;
  bool Find(const uint64_t key) const noexcept;
  uint64_t SizeInBytes() const { return sizeof(Bucket) * (1ull << log_num_buckets_); }

 private:
  // A helper function for Insert()/Find(). Turns a 32-bit hash into a 256-bit Bucket
  // with 1 single 1-bit set in each 32-bit lane.
  static __m256i MakeMask(const uint32_t hash) noexcept;

  SimdBlockFilter(const SimdBlockFilter&) = delete;
  void operator=(const SimdBlockFilter&) = delete;
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include the text of the error message in your post itself so that others can find it and so that the question remains relevant if the image is ever taken down.

Answer (score 0):

That probably means that your include paths aren't setup properly. Try adding `'include_dirs': ["include/path/for/SimdBlockFilter"]` to your binding.gyp.

You should also have `#include "v8.h"` in your source file.